# Undefined reference to "Str::ToInt(unsigned char*)"

Tags: c++, namespaces, undefined-reference

I added a new function into my library, and while compiling Gcc refuse to recognize it.
Every function works without problem, and this is the only one that give problem.

String.hpp

```
#ifndef __String_Included__
#define __String_Included__

namespace Str
{
    //Other prototype
    int ToInt(unsigned char*);
};
#endif
```

String.cpp

```
int ToInt(unsigned char* Source)
{
    //Codecodecodecodecodecodecode
}
```

When I call Str::ToInt in the main I get that error.
I'm working on Codeblocks 12.11 and Windows 8

Comment: You didn’t post the complete code (at least one `#endif` is missing). Assuming this is otherwise complete, then your cpp file is missing the namespace.

Comment: You haven't defined `Str::toInt`, you've defined `toInt`...

Comment: Note that names including double underscores anywhere are reserved for the implementation (the C++ compiler and its standard library). You are only allowed to utter them when given explicit permission (e.g., explicit permission is given to use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`).

Comment: Sorry while copy and pasting I forgot the #endif. The missing Str:: it's a pretty stupid error, but thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `Str::ToInt()` as a member of the namespace `Str` but you defined a function outside of any namespace with the same name `ToInt()`. You need to, at least, `Str::` in front of the definition:

```
int Str::ToInt(unsigned char* Source) { ... }
```

Comment: You can also wrap the function definition in `namespace Str { ... }`. The compiler will "merge" the two or more `namespace Str { ... }` blocks. A bit less typing if you have many functions in the namespace.